# How to Swap 2 Range in word documnet

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

How i can swap 2 ranges in word, i have list and try to sort them manually
each range have locked content control

**I try the below code but no success:**

```
object Unit = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdWord;
object Count = (toPosition - sourceStart);
range.Move(Unit, Count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
 range = documents.Range(sourceStart, sourceEnd);
 range.Select();
 range.Cut();
 var range1 = documents.Range(DestinationStart, DestinationStart);
 range1.InsertParagraphAfter();
 range1 = documents.Range(range1.End, range1.End);
 range1.Paste();
```